# How to convert Date using SimpleDate Format?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date

In my Java application I am using Mysql and it returns  date in format as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`. Though I need that in format `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a`. The conversion does happen in an Hibernate VO class.

For this purpose I am doing like that:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
private Date createdDate = new Date();

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh-mm a")
                .parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(createdDate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
```

But it does give a Parse exception.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-05-06 01:39:00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:354)
    at com.sits.ec.valueObjects.MessageBoxVO.getCreatedDate(MessageBoxVO.java:64)
```

Can anyone give me an advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Why would you format a date and parse it again to get back the date object? You could directly use the actual date object as such.

Secondly, you're formatting a date with `format1` and then trying to parse that with `format2`, which is not the same as `format1`. Hence, the `ParseException`.

This is what you need.

```
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
```

Comment: if we directly return the createDate object it is going same like.. yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format but i want 'dd/MM/yyyy hh-mm a' this format

Comment: `Date` has no formatting. You can only get a `String` representation in the format required by you. You either get a `String` in the format you need, or you get the Date object.

Comment: `Date to Date` - is absolutely pointless, as you can format `Date` object. You can only get a `String` representation of that `Date` object in the format required by you!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a")
        String s = df.format(now);
        System.out.println("Today is: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is simple one converting Date to String but i want Date to Date but my own format...

Comment: @java The object Date doesn't specify a format, it only stores an amount of time in a Long variable. It's part of the client that is going to visualize that date to define the format.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is fundamentally wrong with your code: it accepts a `Date` and returts a `Date`. `Date` has nothing to do with strings, it represents an absolute instant in time. If you at least got the outside API right, we may be able to propose an implementation.

Comment: Yes, i want Date to Date but first date was some other format and second date was some other format..

Comment: As I point out, `Date` is in no format whatsoever, it is a wrapper around a `long` value you can get from `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Your request is tantamount to asking for an `int` which has the same value but in a "different format".

Answer (score 1):

Try This One:

```
String time=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to parse a String representation of `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` date format into this `dd/MM/yyyy hh-mm a` date format. How do you expect that to work?

Representation must match.

Answer (score 0):

Try only
`String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a").format(createdDate);`
There is nothing more needed.

Answer (score 0):

`return createdDate;` is all you need.

There is no point in formatting a `Date` object to a `String` and then parse that `String` back to a `Date` object.

Btw it would work if you used the same format pattern for the parse and format operation.

Update: If you want the Date as formatted String you can use this:

```
public String getCreatedDateAsString() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a").format(createdDate);
}
```

`java.util.Date` merely represents a single millisecond in time since 1.1.1980 GMT and knows absolutely nothing about time formats and things like that.

Comment: Its `toString` method does produce a date in some format (not very relevant, but makes your statement not literally true).